# Python Keras:input size: train neural network for regression task where each sample observation is array itself

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

My data matrix looks as follows. [dataframe][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjpHX.png
The observations for each variable itself are an array and I was wondering how I could change the inpu tsize of keras to accept my arrays:
Here is what I have tried but I don't seem to be able to get the input size correct for my data.
Or is there another package thats more suitalbe

```
Y = dataset[:,13]
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, **input_dim=13**, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(los='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, Y, cv=kfold)
```

Comment: Are sizes of arrays in one column always the same?

Comment: Unfortunatly I just realized no how could I make them all the same length? say fill them up with them mean or so to have same length? i get the following error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence